# MP3: a way to get position in milliseconds for any given byte position?

Tags: java, mp3, audio-streaming

I've created a servlet which returns a stream (from an MP3 file) beginning at any given byte position requested by a client. This allows the client to start playback instantly at any given byte position without doing any local seek.

Now, I've got a slider which visualises the progress. I'm using the the current byte position to update the slider. However, I'd also like to show the current position in seconds.

This requires that the server can "convert" the current position in bytes to the position in milliseconds. The server could then just provided the stream start position in milliseconds as a response header.

Does anyone have experience as to how one can calculate the current position in bytes to milliseconds?

**UPDATE**

It is clear, from the comments, that there is no precise way to get convert bytes to milliseconds and vice versa without decoding the MP3 file up to the point (in milliseconds or bytes) and then determine how many bytes that have been read or milliseconds that have been played. However, this approach would obviously not perform too well considering a server where, say, 100 users would request files at the same time. The server would then have to decode the MP3 files up to the requested position, and then return streams from that point. I chose to exchange precision with performance, and took an approach which gives me approximate positions and which is more than good enough for a player which purpose is just to play a track (and not synch the audio against other sources down to the millisecond).

What I've done is that the player (on the client side) only cares about milliseconds (MS) now. That is, the current value and maximum value of the progress bar is in MS, and not bytes as it first did. To begin playback from any given position, the client requests the server (servlet) to provide the audio stream beginning at any given position in MS. The servlet use JAudioTagger to get details about the file, and then makes an approximate calculation as to what byte position the MS position corresponds to. I've tested it and it works well with CBR (constant bitrate) files. The approach will not work with VBR (variable bitrate) files as frame size can vary. Please note that this is just a player which purpose is to play music files. It's not intended to synchronize the audio against some other media down to the MS. The code snipped which converts from MS to bytes is provided below.

**UPDATE (July 3, 2012)**

The servlet has been running with the below code for quite a while now, and things work very well. Thousands of MP3's have been played, and the approximation from ms to bytes works fine.

**UPDATE (January 3, 2017)**

The servlet is still running with this exact same code, and hundreds of thousands of MP3s have been played nicely. During it's time in production, no single complaint has been made with regards to playback and timing.

```
/**
 * Returns the approximate byte position for any given position in
 * milliseconds.
 *
 * http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android/Mp3/needletagger/org/jaudiotagger/audio/mp3/MP3AudioHeader.java.htm
 * http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/topic29420.html
 *
 * @param   file the <code>File</code> for which the byte position for the
 *          provided position in milliseconds is to be returned.
 * @param   ms a <code>long</code> being the position in milliseconds for
 *          which the corresponding byte position is to be returned.
 * @return  a <code>long</code> being the byte position, or <b>-1</b> if the
 *          position in bytes could not be obtained.
 */
public static long getApproximateBytePositionForMilliseconds(File file, long ms) {

    long bytePosition = -1;

    try {

        AudioFile audioFile = AudioFileIO.read(file);
        AudioHeader audioHeader = audioFile.getAudioHeader();

        if (audioHeader instanceof MP3AudioHeader) {
            MP3AudioHeader mp3AudioHeader = (MP3AudioHeader) audioHeader;
            long audioStartByte = mp3AudioHeader.getMp3StartByte();
            long audioSize = file.length() - audioStartByte;
            long frameCount = mp3AudioHeader.getNumberOfFrames();
            long frameSize = audioSize / frameCount;

            double frameDurationInMs = (mp3AudioHeader.getPreciseTrackLength() / (double) frameCount) * 1000;
            double framesForMs = ms / frameDurationInMs;
            long bytePositionForMs = (long) (audioStartByte + (framesForMs * frameSize));
            bytePosition = bytePositionForMs;
        }

        return bytePosition;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return bytePosition;
    }

}
```

Comment: MP3 doesn't work like WAVE files. MP3 works in frames (their data are "chunked" in frame blocks) while WAVE files works in byte arrays (WAVE files are raw, unprocessed data). Just a tip! :)

Comment: The Elite Gentleman : thanks for your tip. Nevertheless, it should be possible to get the ms position for any given byte position, even though it would just be an approximate position (nearest)?

Comment: *"though it would just be an approximate position (nearest)? "*  Not so much 'approximate' as 'arbitrary'.  Are you familiar with VBR MP3s?

Comment: @sbrattla, not quite. Some MP3 files have constant bit-rates (CBR) and some are variable bit-rates (VBR). These detetermines the size of the frame, so you will need to read the frames and do calculations to near accuracy.

Comment: Do you think my approach as described in the comment under Kilian Foths answer would work. I know the total length of the stream in bytes and seconds, and then just "convert" the byteposition to the timescale. It might not work well with variable bitrate, but with constant bitrate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work like that. Even if your MP3 file is constant-bit-rate encoded, which byte position encodes which second in the stream is variable. (To be sure, VBR encoding makes it a lot *more* variable than CBR, but all the same.) The only way to reliably get this information is to actually decode the stream up to that point, which you probably don't want to do. This is why even professional players such as XMMS cannot reliably update the slider when you skip around.

Comment: How does YouTube then go about to give me the position in seconds? Does it just know the total length of the stream (from 0 to end) and then "convert" the current byteposition to whatever that would be on the time scale?

Comment: @sbrattla, if you look closely, it actually doesn't.  Try skipping ahead and backward.  You will find that you can only seek to "keyframes", which are frames of full data.  Subsequent frames have variations on the keyframe.  There are ways of predetermining offset and accessing that data for an MP3 file, but in any case, the whole file has to be decoded first.

Comment: @Brad, this is just my thoughts, but if one assume all files are CBR, it seems to me that I can get the size of each frame and duration of each frame and then make an approximate conversion from ms offset to byte offset? As far as i understand it, this is how other libraries do it. Is this wrong then?

Comment: Approximate is one thing... you were looking for down to the millisecond level.  CBR is not actually completely a constant bit rate.  Some frames have information from other frames, depending on what the encoder thinks it needs to best approximate the audio in the frame.  You could get an approximate position with a CBR file, sure.  Keep in mind that at 44.1kHz, the length of a frame is a hair more than 26ms.

Comment: Look at it this way: the point of MP3 is to save space by removing the psycho-acoustically unimportant stuff from the signal. Usually, there isn't the same amount of redundancy in every part of a piece, so having a *completely* constant  bit rate would force you to fluctuate wildly between very good and much worse fidelity, Since no one would accept that, you just set a target for the acceptable size per second and try to keep to that figure when averaged over multiple frames.

Comment: I'll mark this one as the accepted answer as this is the answer which gave the best discussion and most insight. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 4):

An MP3 file or stream is a sequence of frames, where each frame consists of a mp3 header and a mp3 data part.

header and data part information are used to create a audio frame that "sounds like the original".

Therefore a position in the mp3 file or stream can't be converted to a timestamp in the resulting audio stream.

Answer (score 0):

The "hardest" way is doing a loop. Inside the loop you call your `play()` or `player.play()` method and after that put your thread to sleep for just enough milis so as the song can finish without starting the next song over it, but you must estimate for example a song with 7mb size has aproximately duration of about 3 minutes so you must sleep your thread in this space. Your song length is given by `Files.readAllBytes(Path path)`. Something like that:

```
//i put 5 for example lets say 5 songs//
//1000000 bytes is 1MB the same calculation is the same for the rest  length numbers//
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
   play();
   if(length>1000000 && length<7500000){
     try{
        Thread.sleep(milis);
     }
     catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace;
}
```

You must create a byte[]array=Files.readAllBytes(Path path) and then a variable int length=array.length so as for every song to take its length.This method that i show is not super good but with a little attension it works fine enough.

Comment: How does this answer attempt to address the question?

Comment: the whole idea is tha by getting the song legth there is a way to match it with milis so as you can handle several tasks tha your song may do ex.(stop ,pause...).I know my answer is bit of topic.