# Amazon s3 Loading music files faster

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jakarta-ee, amazon-s3, streaming

I need to download(or possibly stream) a song from an Amazon s3 bucket. The problem is that if the song is say 270 seconds long I want to start the download/stream at 150 seconds into the song and then play it from there.

How do i acomplish this using Amazon s3 web services and Java EE servlet technology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [AWS Java SDK](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/sdk-for-java/), you should use [AmazonS3Client](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html), and call [getObject](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getObject(com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest)) on it with an instance of [GetObjectRequest](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GetObjectRequest.html). When creating your request, call [setRange](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/GetObjectRequest.html#setRange(long,%20long)) with the byte range to get. This will let you get a portion of the file without downloading the entire thing. `getObject()` returns an S3Object which you can use to stream the file contents to a music player or local file or whatever you want.

There are two tricky parts:

One tricky part is that you probably need the song's header bytes as well. E.g. if the file is in MP3 format, you need the [MP3 header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure). You can use the same method above to fetch the byte range of the header.

The other tricky part is how to determine the byte offset in a file from a number of seconds into the song. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7267927/mp3-a-way-to-get-position-in-miliseconds-for-any-given-byte-position) regarding that. You could easily estimate byte offset by getting the entire file size in bytes (see [getObjectMetadata](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#getObjectMetadata(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))), dividing by the total length of the song in seconds, and multiplying by the number of seconds to offset the download.

Comment: I have tried that exactly and contemplated those tricky parts as well before I had asked this question. I kept getting a java io.eofexception that i couldn't seem to solve. I will try to recreate my code then edit my question with the code included if the error persists

Comment: I got it working I have no idea what I did differently thank you though without your reassuring of my suspicions i wouldn't have gone back to it

Comment: actually it worked when I set the range from (0-whatever) but if i try (anythingoverzero-whatever) it doesnt work and i get a javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException

Comment: That's because the audio file format e.g. mp3 is batched into frames that span multiple bytes. When you just pick an arbitrary byte offset that isn't aligned to one of those pieces it makes the file unreadable. If you can figure out how big a frame is in bytes you could align your byte offset to that. See http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm for some more information. That site says that several forms of MPEG audio allow for splitting on frames. Also you can ask another question on SO specifically about this problem.